# ScheduledExecutorService is not shutting down

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I need to stop all the scheduled runnables when shutting down this executor I save the scheduled futures in a list when using `execute(Runnable runnable)`, however, this does not work, the runnables are still being runned after calling `shutdown` but i'm in fact stopping them using `scheduledFutures.forEach(scheduledFuture -> scheduledFuture.cancel(false))` in that method, why does this happen?.

```
public class ThreadPool {
    private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPoolExecutor;

    private final List<ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduledFutures = new ArrayList<>();

    public ThreadPool(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPoolExecutor) {
        this.scheduledThreadPoolExecutor = scheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
    }

    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        scheduledFutures.add(
            scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        scheduledFutures.forEach(scheduledFuture -> scheduledFuture.cancel(false));
        scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
        try {
            if (scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                return;
            }
            scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How long do your scheduled tasks normally take?  `cancel(false)` doesn’t guarantee they’ll stop, if they’re in progress.

Comment: @VGR its just a repeated task, but I want be able to stop it

Comment: And how long does that task take to run each time?

Comment: @VGR hmm I don't understand what you mean, it is a repeated task has no end

Comment: How long does it take for the task to run *once?*